# android SDK 32 bit and 64 bit compatibility

Tags: android, sdk

I'm planning to develop and android app. Will projects written under a 32 bit installation of the SDK by compatible with the 64 bit SDK? (i.e will I be able to export and import projects between the 64 bit and 32 bit SDKs ? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,it is compatible for same project Because only platforms are different but resource is android only. So, 32 bit installation of SDK is compatible with 64 bit SDK.